# How can I capitalize the first character of a sentence with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm just about pulling my hair here. I have a function that I made (found and modified) To make text title case. The reason I use this function Instead of just capitalizing the first letter of every word is because there are many words That should not be capitalized.

The code that I have here works. Now all I need is for it to capitalize the first character of every sentence. So after it finished is the function, create a new function that will capitalize the first character of the new string. I just can't figure out how to do this in his driving me crazy. Thank you so much for all your help guys I appreciate it.

```
var TITLECASE = function (str, glue) {
  glue = (glue) ? glue : ['a', 'and', 'as', 'at', 'but', 'by', 'for', 'if', 'in', 'is', 'it', 'my', 'nor', 'of', 'off', 'on', 'or', 'per', 'so', 'the', 'this', 'to', 'up', 'via', 'with', 'yet'];
  return str.replace(/(\w)(\w*)/g, function (_, i, r) {
    var j = i.toUpperCase() + (r != null ? r : "");
    return (glue.indexOf(j.toLowerCase()) < 0) ? j : j.toLowerCase();
  });
};
```

Comment: What is your criteria for the first word of a sentence?

Comment: The solution has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to capitalize the first letter in any sentence you can try using charAt + toUppercase like so;

```js
var input="hello this is a sentence";

var output=input.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+input.substr(1,test.length);
// Hello this is a sentence
```

Comment: Hi and thank you so much for your comment. I'm trying what you've provided now. I think there's something wrong with my implementation. Also I noticed that you wrote "test" instead of "text" In one instance. This was a mistake correct? either way, here is the new code, still not working. :/.

Comment: var TITLECASE = function(str, small){
    small = (small) ? small : ['a','and','as','at','an','by','this','if','is'];
    return str.replace(/(\w)(\w*)/g, function(_, i, r){
        var j = i.toUpperCase() + (r != null ? r : "");
        var text = (small.indexOf(j.toLowerCase())<0)?j:j.toLowerCase();
       return (text) 
    });
  line = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+text.substr(1,text.length);
  return (line);
};
TITLECASE("this is an example ")

Comment: I'm sorry if that wasn't the right place to put the code. I'm new to stack overflow. And I'm not sure where to paste the code that I have just added.